# Show that for any $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, $3 \mid(a^3 - a)$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, induction, modular-arithmetic, congruences

Show that for any $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, $3 \mid (a^3 - a)$

my solution is : if $a$ is a multiple of $3$ then $a^3-a$ is a multiple of $3$; if $\gcd(a,3)=1$ then by FLT $a^2\equiv 1 \pmod3$, hence $a^3-a = a(a^2-1)$ is a multiple of $3$.

Am I right?

Comment: Since $3$ is prime, $a^3 \equiv a \pmod 3$ by Fermat's little theorem. In case you wanted another approach.

Comment: and then what do I need to do next? apply the theorem?

Comment: Please see my answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: you can use $a^3-a=a(a+1)(a-1)$ one between 3 consecutive numbers is divisible by 3

Comment: thank you. I need to factor it also!

Answer (score 2):

Verify that $0^3 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$, $1^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, and $2^3 \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$, and that's all there is to it.  Fermat's little theorem is overkill for this.

Answer (score 0):

Since $3$ is prime, by Fermat's little theorem we have $a^3 \equiv a \pmod 3$. Thus $a^3 - a \equiv 0 \pmod 3$. We conclude that $3 \mid (a^3 - a)$.

Comment: but can I apply any factoring for $a^3$ - a ? because on the textbook, it says hint : start by factoring and think about remainders.

Comment: Yes, see @TsemoAristide's solution. I simply presented another solution using a well-known theorem, but it is overkill.

Comment: oh I see. Alright thank you . I will remember the solution that you provided and use on the test because I think it is more understandable. Thank you :))

Comment: @guest11 Yes but be careful, have you learned to use Fermat's last theorem in the textbook or lecture?

Comment: I am self-learner so I don't have a lecture class that's why there are many questions that I don't understand. But Fermat's Theorem is $a^p-1$ congruent 1 mod p ... is that right?

Comment: @guest11 Yes, that is the less general version and requires $p \not\mid a$ in addition to $p$ being prime. The most general version is the one I gave

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31579/discussion-between-guest11-and-mathmajor).